# Using Quest Geo Solutions GIQ60 library on a 64bit machine

Tags: sql-server, ssis, geocoding, 32bit-64bit, 16-bit

We are using Quest Geo Solution's Grid InQuest DLL (GIQ60.DLL) within an SQL Server Integration  Services (SSIS) package. We have managed to use this without problems locally (32bit) by using tlbimp to create a .NET wrapper (interop). However, when this moved to our integration server this does not work as the server is 64bit.

The GIQ60.DLL is a 16bit DLL and the vendor has confirmed that they no longer actively support this. If we run the 32bit version of DTEXEC on the server , the package runs without problems. Is there a trick/way to convert the .NET wrapper to enable this to work SQL Server Integration Services (64bit install).

Alternatively , we need a replacement free 32bit .net library that will convert OS grid (Easting /Northings) into geospatial longitude/latitude for both UK and Ireland (they use different grid systems) then that would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other solution i can think of is to create a windows service (32bit) that hosts your component and exposes it as WCF or Remoting end point. Then use script task in SSIS to access it. This way you can run your package in 64bit DTEXEC and your component in 32bit process.

HTH

Comment: We are looking at converting a javascript implementation of the conversion routines to c#. However, this is by far the closest solution to getting the 16bit DLL work so it gets the coverted accepted answer tick.

Answer (score 0):

In one environment I support, there is an SSIS package that relies on a certain version of a connection to Lotus Notes. That dll is a 32 bit dll and it doesn't work when executing in SSIS on the 64Bit production server.

We simple execute the SSIS package with a command prompt call to the 32Bit version of DTEXEC. That works fine.

You might try that to avoid having to maintain two different versions of code?

Comment: As I said, If we run the 32bit version of DTEXEC on the server , the package runs without problems. We dont want to do that. The DLL is def 16bit, which runs fine under 32bit DTEXEC. We are looking for alternative 32bit DLL solution so if you have any ideas please let me know.